How can we visualise the induced electric field in a loop placed in a changing magnetic field?
We know, when a rod is moved in a magnetic field, an EMF is induced in the rod beacuse of induced Electric field.

Here we can see that the positive charge accumulates on one end and negative on the other due to the magnetic force. This leads to formation of electric field which leads to an induced EMF.
My question is that, how can we visualise the electric field in case of a loop placed in a changing magnetic field? Since no charge will be accumulated at any place in what sense the Electric field will be produced?


It's a common misconception to think that the first and second scenario that you mentioned are caused by the same effect. In the first scenario you are right, Electric field is produced by the charge distribution inside a rod, which was caused by the magnetic field. You find the induced electric field by working out the condition that the charge distribution has already settled (doesn't necessarily  mean that a free electron is not accelerating, for example take a rotating metal disk in an uniform magnetic field). In the second case however electric field is induced everywhere in space according to one of Maxwell's equations:
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$ This law is an experimental result. In the first case the electric field is directly caused by the charge distribution inside a metal and in the second case the induced electric field comes from the outside source and can exist without anything being put into a changing magnetic field, unlike the first case. However you can prove that for non-relativistic velocities of a metal  the equation: $$\mathcal{E} = -\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$$ Where $d\Phi_B$ is a flux that is "swept" by the metal in a time $dt$, gives you the same result in the first scenario as the method mentioned already. For complete metal loops the above equation just boils down to the rate of change of the flux inside that loop, which looks a lot like faradays law of induction,(Which is just an integral form of the Maxwell's equation above) that tells you that the induced EMF in an imaginary loop fixed in space is equal to a time derivative of a magnetic flux inside that loop. Two physical effects are not the same but you can still use faraday's law of induction for moving loops and get the correct results.
